# What is a path?

Tags: path

I'm trying to install this add-on to a program, where I have to 'make sure the executable file is in your PATH'.

What does this mean? I've tried placing this file along the path of a file I need when working in the program, but then the add-on doesn't seem to work..

Could anyone tell me what is meant with the line 'make sure the executable file is in your PATH'?

Cheers!
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATH in an environment variable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). If you execute a program, the system searches in directories defined in this variable for the binary to be executed. In your case, you have to make sure that either a) your program is in a directory which is in your PATH variable or b) add the directory where your program is located to the PATH.

As I don't know which operating system you're using, I can't tell you how to do it exactly. But there are plenty of tutorials online on how to modify the PATH.